# How to find the closest descendants (that matches a selector) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

We can use `closest(selector)` to find the first ancestor element that matches the selector. It travels **up** the DOM tree until it finds a match for the selector. But what if I want to travels **down** the DOM tree until it finds a match for the selector? Is there any jQuery function for doing this? Or do I need to implement this using breadth-first search?

Give an example. For the DOM tree below,

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <ul><!-- I want to match this ul -->
            <li>
                <ul><!-- but not this ul -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul><!-- and match this ul -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to do something like `$('#main').closestDescendants('ul')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might suffice:

```
$('#main ul:not(#main ul ul)')
```

If you need something more accurate then you can use each() to iterate the list of elements, calculate the shortest path to #main, and filter out those elements where the path is longer than this.

Comment: This requires that you have some anchor point #main rather than just scoping it to some context element.  Is there a way to write this so that it is just relative to a scope AND that it will not match to elements whose match is based on an ancestor higher up than the context scope?

Answer (score 1):

So, the closestChild plugin links are broken for me.  Here's an implementation:

```
$.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
    var nearest = $(), node = this, distance = 10000;
    node.find(selector).each(function(){
        var n = $(this),
            d = n.parentsUntil(node).size();
        if (d < distance) {
            distance = d;
            nearest = n;
        } else if (d == distance) {
            nearest = nearest.add(this);
        }
    });
    return nearest;
};
```

Comment: In the tradition of jQuery it is not standard to return undefined if a selector fails. It's better to return an empty jQuery object. In the above snippet, initialize 'nearest' properly, i.e.: replace 'var nearest' with 'var nearest = $()'.

Comment: The former plugin database from jQuery is lost. The "clostestChild" plugin is now availabel in the new plugin database under the name "closestDescendant" http://plugins.jquery.com/closestDescendant/

Comment: At this time (not sure if it was ever different), `nearest.add(this)` in line 10 will not actually change the value of `nearest`, because `.add()` creates a new set and leaves the original unchanged. Instead, try `nearest = nearest.add(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Will the elements you want to match always be a child of a div?  If so, you could match using .children('ul') syntax.  It would be best to put a Id/Class on the div, so you could do the following...

```
$('#menu').children('ul');

<div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul><!-- I want to match this ul -->
            <li>
                <ul><!-- but not this ul -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul><!-- and match this ul -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: level difference between $('#main') and its closest ul descendants can vary, and only $('#main') have determinate id.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and needed a much more generic solution, so I wrote a function for it and decided to package it up as a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/childrenUntil). I know this thread is pretty old, but please have a look and let me know what you think.